# django+redis+celery: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: django-models, redis, celery

I have the problem of [Errno 111] Connection refused. this happens in between the tasks. my django project runs on CentOS7.

If I activate the celery worker (inside my django project root path) and run in the terminal using below command, it works without any problem.

```
celery -A mysite worker -l info
```

But when I run the celery worker in Daemonization, using below command, even I did not shut down the terminal window, it appears the problem of "[Errno 111] Connection refused". this often happens in between the tasks.

```
celery -A mysite multi start worker1 \
    --pidfile="/www/wwwroot/myapp/celerypid.pid " \
    --logfile="/www/wwwroot/myapp/celerylog.log"
```

what is the underlying issue here, how to solve this problem?